# Show or Hide content user role wise

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm developing a website in wordpress using Woocommerce and WC Vendor Marketplace plugin. I want to show content on certain page user role wise in wordpress website.

For example.
If i'm login as a vendor then it shows content "A" and if i'm login as a customer then it hides content "A".

Here i'm customize my own code for this but not work.

```
    <?php 
    $userss =get_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'wp_capabilities', true );
    if ($userss='vendor') {
        echo'<li id="menuuu"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button7" style="background- color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000">Back To Dashboard</a>';
        echo'</li>';
    }                 
    ?>               
<?php endif; ?>
```

In above code 'wp_capabilities' is for user role in wordpress. In my code, user roles are 'vendor' and 'customer'. I'm really weak in php. So please help me.

Comment: Here i want to show <li id="menuuu"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button7" style="background- color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000">Back To Dashboard</a></li> but if vendor is login.  But if i'm a customer then this link not visible for customer role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wp_capabilities data store as serilized array of user role instead of this you can use current_user_can for more information you can refer to [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/).
You can change your code as below:

```
if (current_user_can('vendor')) {
    echo'<li id="menuuu"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button7" style="background- color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000">Back To Dashboard</a>';
    echo'</li>';
}
?>               
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please vote this question so that needy peoples get the appropriate  way. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been marked answered, however using current_user_can() with roles is unreliable and even says as much in the codex.

> While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.

It's better to use our built in methods to determine if the current user is a vendor.

```
<?php if ( WCV_Vendors::is_vendor( $vendor_id ) ) : ?>
<li id="menuuu"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="button7" style="background- color:#CCCCCC; color:#000000">Back To Dashboard</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain How above code produce unreliable results?. I know @IncipientInfo code is right.

Comment: As per the WordPress Codex says it produces unreliable results. The function current_user_can is for testing capabilities first and roles, kind of.  If you have multiple roles then current_user_can can produce inconsistent results. Also as the lead developer and founder of WC Vendors, I would suggest you use our built in methods for determining who a vendor is.